# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobCounter.MB_MILLIS_MAPS

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hadoop2

I am trying to run a dump command on a schema in pig,but I am getting following error:

```
empdata.txt contents:
1001,kapil,B.A,11000.00,HYDERABAD
1002,vasu,LLB,9500.00,CALCUTTA
1003,satyam,ENGINEER,11000.00,MUMBAI
1004,vani,SOFTWARE,9500.00,DELHI
1005,srinivas,B.COM,11000.00,NAGPUR
1006,neelesh,B.ED,12500.00,MUMBAI

Command used in pig::

EMP = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:8020/user/anshumahajan/empdata.txt' Using PigStorage(',') AS (id,name,designation,salary,city);

DUMP EMP;

Error::
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobCounter.MB_MILLIS_MAPS
```

Hadoop version is 2.5.2
Pig version is pig-release-0.12.1
Both are on same machine with no replication.

Answer (score 0):

When we don't specify PIG_CLASSPATH, pig uses default environment variables HBASE_HOME , HADOOP_HOME etc. In my case HBASE_HOME was having older hadoop. I solved it by setting export PIG_CLASSPATH="`hadoop classpath`" i.e value of hadoop classpath